# What is Google Partner Setup?

Tags: security, google, permissions, privacy, google-apps

What does the `Google Partner Setup` app that is pre-installed on almost every Android device actually do?

Why does it need each of those intrusive permissions, especially the `Phone` permission?

Why does it want internet access, and what data is it transmitting or receiving?

Comment: Google Partner Setup was *not* preinstalled on my recently purchased Galaxy Note 10, but it installed itself after I had been playing with the phone for about two days. I suspect that the installation was triggered by the first-time use of some other app that would like to use Google Partner Setup, but I don't know what app that might be. IAC, on my Note 10, Version 9-566081 claims not to need any privileges. P.S. Perhaps the installation was triggered by my use of Google text-to-speech services,

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Google Partner Setup is an app that helps you run applications in conjunction with Google products. For example, with this application's help, you can use the calendar from your device with a ToDo app that you've just installed.

As for the intrusive permissions, you are right. I don't understand why it needs all those permissions, if all it does is interface with other Google products. This software cannot be downloaded or deleted because it comes with certain hardware.

I am not sure, what the result of deleting this app (on rooted device) could be. I have just greenified this app on my android tablet, I'll report back if I face any issues.

Source: http://answers.informer.com/68993/what-does-google-partner-setup-for-do-i-need-it-on-my-phone

Comment: Its been around a week and no issues yet. The system performs great without the overhead of the Google Partner Setup! Only problem is that it starts on its own frequently, and you need to manually greenify/hibernate it every now and then (unless you are rooted, of course, in which case it should happen automatically).